# What is the closed form of this summation?

Tags: summation

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}{2k}x^n
$$

$k$ is a constant integer.

First I want to find the relation between $\binom{n+k}{2k}$'s, but failed, then I change $f(x)$ to $f(k,x)$, want to figure the relations of $f(k,x)$, but still cannot find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought: $n\geq k$. Or else ${n+k\choose 2k}$ won't be defined. So what you're looking at is ${2k\choose 2k}x^{k} + {2k+1\choose 2k}x^{k+1}+\dots$

Comment: There is an answer posted.  But better would be some help.  Can you do the case $k=0$?  Can you do the case $k=1$?  Do these cases give you some ideas for a more general case?

Answer (score 10):

$$f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}{2k}x^n= x^k\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{2k+n}{2k}x^n=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{2k+1}}.$$
Take a look at this  [wiki article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Series_involving_binomial_coefficients)

Comment: +1, but always better, when changing variables, to change the variable name, when you can. I'd write $\sum_{m\geq 0}\dots$ for the right side of the substitution.

Comment: Thx! I learn a new equation $\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n}{k}x^n=x^k/(1-x)^{k+1}$ now.